# MSMQ transactional queue, in-order delivery

Tags: msmq

Is it possible to enforce in-order receiving on MSMQ message queues? i.e. we want to receive the messages in the same order as they've been sent.

Edit: If it helps: transactional queues are fine with us. No DTC would be better.

Edit2 - some additional context: When a user commits new data to our database (via a web interface), our web application publishes events onto a service bus (using MSMQ under the hood). Listeners on the bus should now receive the messages in-order, as this is important for consistency (person cannot be renamed before created...). The bus guys just do the creating of the queues for each point-to-point connection and subscription management, however, they said the underlying queue is in charge of delivering the events in-order.

Comment: FYI - this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1931957/21727) didn't get any responses.

Comment: I know, it is really hard to find any information about it. Sometimes I only find very old information (7 years and older) and so I've started a new topic. Hope that's ok!

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1675448/21727) might help clarify your issue.

Comment: I added some context, thank you for the link, however, I don't see a match to our context...

Comment: So is your problem that the web application isn't publishing events to MSMQ in the proper order?

Comment: The web application is publishing the events in proper order, however MSMQ does not seem to guarantee in-order delivery - or is it? Could not find any definitive documentation about this.

Comment: By "in-order delivery", do you mean 1) The items are not inserted into the incoming queue in order, 2) The items are not consumed and placed in the outgoing queue in the same order they appeared in the incoming queue, or 3) The items in the outgoing queue are not sent in order?

Comment: The items consumed in the receiving application are not in the same order than we put them into the queue in the sending application. I don't know exactly yet, which of your three cases is the problem, however, you say it should be possible to retrieve them all in-order? You sure?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that where the issue is will determine if it is fixable or not.  For example, if you have multiple consumers asynchronously processing incoming items, then you cannot expect them to finish in the original order.  In that case, one solution would be to only have 1 consumer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to ensure messages arrive in a queue in the order they are to be read from the queue is by sending them all within one transaction.

You can send multiple messages outside of a transaction and it is very likely indeed that they will arrive in the queue in the order they were sent BUT it is not guaranteed. You would therefore need to write error-handling code to deal with an out-of-order situation.

Comment: This is a different answer as I suspected after mbeckish' comments on my initial post. Are you sure about your information?

Comment: Yes, pretty confident. Spent several years in MSMQ support at Microsoft and often liased with the product group. Although the sending of messages in order looks easy on the surface, it's the plumbing under the covers that is important. So we're talking about the network packets on the wire with their retry mechanisms and transmission windows, for example, or the multi-threading of the MSMQ service on the receiver which mean it is theoretically possible for messages to overtake each other. In practice, it's very hard to force it, though.